# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: _MSImageSelectionIsDoneNotification

Tags: macos, cocoa, x86-64

I've been trying to solve this problem, but can't find a solution.

I have a MSCropImageView defining

```
extern NSString * const MSImageSelectionIsDoneNotification;
```

in its header, and

```
NSString * const MSImageSelectionIsDoneNotification = @"MSApp.MSImageSelectionIsDoneNotification";
```

in MSCropImageView.m

but when I call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectionIsDone:) name:MSImageSelectionIsDoneNotification object:self.imageView];
```

from another file I get the error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. I'v included the header file that defines the symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't just the header file that's needed, my guess is that MSCropImageView.m is not actually included in your built app.

In other words, go to the list of files for your project and then open the "File Inspector" view (which is along the right side).  For me it looks like this:

[image: Make sure Target Membership is selected for your .m file]

Make sure the checkbox that's circled is checked for your built app.